# html-agility-pack avoid parsing nodes within TextArea

Tags: html-agility-pack

Html-agility-pack seems to build nodes from elements within TextArea, which are not real nodes.
For example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
<title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
<TEXTAREA>Text in the <div>hello</div>area</TEXTAREA>
</body>
</html>
```

This will yield a child-node of "div" under the "textarea".
Browsers will treat everything as text.

Is there a way to compel html-agility-pack to behave the same way?

**Clarification**

I don't want the node to be created in the first place. If I run `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div")` I want this to yield nothing. Right now I have to use `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div [not(ancestor::textarea]")` but I have to do this for every select I perform to avoid phantom nodes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `InnerText` property to get just the text of a node. This also gets the text of any child nodes (in this case the `div`).

```
var textArea = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//textarea");

string text = textArea.InnerText;
```

Comment: Please note that for the sample HTML above, `InnerText` yields _Text in the helloarea_. To get what you intended you need to use `InnerHtml`.

Comment: @ShaharSperling *Browsers will treat everything as text.* You say you wanted just the text, not the inner nodes... that's what `InnerText` gives.

Comment: I tested 4 different browsers. All `innerHTML` calls yield _Text in the &lt;div&gt;hello&lt;/div&gt;area_ and and empty string when calling `innerText` except for IE which yields _Text in the <div>hello</div>area_. Html-agility-pack yields _Text in the helloarea_ for innerText and _Text in the <div>hello</div>area_ when calling `innerHTML` (making this a valid HTML, not a text). I am using html-agility-pack 1.7.1. Is there a different version where the results are different?

Comment: @ShaharSperling maybe I'm not understanding exactly what it is you are hoping to parse from you sample html. Can you explain exactly what you are hoping to parse out of that sample?

Comment: I'm trying to get a correct DOM parsed. Right now, the DOM includes a child node <div> under the <textarea> where it should not have one. <textarea> can not have child HTML nodes.

Comment: Are you parsing this html from a website? If that's the case, you wouldn't have control over the html they are sending.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been fixed by the kind folks at zzzprojects.

Fix available and tested on version 1.8.2.

You can see the ticket here: [Issue 183](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/issues/183#issuecomment-384659885)